# How to set up an iTunes podcast?

Tags: 8, feeds

[This question about podcasting in Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50286/podcasting-with-drupal-7) recommends the [Views RSS iTunes elements](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rss_itunes) module, which hasn't had any commits on the Drupal 8 dev branch since 2014. ([tutorial for D7](https://www.chenhuijing.com/blog/drupal-101-generating-itunes-rss/))

The [iTunes RSS tag documentation](https://help.apple.com/itc/podcasts_connect/#/itcb54353390) shows that the tags are not very complex, and indeed the [iTunes elements module (D7)](https://www.drupal.org/node/1473728) documentation shows that there are only about a dozen tags that need to be set up for an iTunes-compatible podcast.

So my question is, do any of the additional features of D8 compared to D7 provide a way to configure this with just the modules in core, or am I going to have to code something to generate an RSS feed that meets the iTunes podcasting requirements?

I was hoping to be able to use something like a Views theming template to just rewrite all the tags in the template and publish the feed that way.

Comment: I had to write my own theme function and route and created feed like that. I do not know about any readily available solution for Drupal as of now. Normally I wouldn't do this but maybe have a look at Wordpress? It has few good modules for this.

Comment: Have you looked into using Views for your RSS? Perhaps you can override or create custom tags with views.

Comment: @NoSssweat Yes, I'm interested in using Views to create custom tags, but how?

Answer (score 1):

Just because there hasn't been a commit for ages doesn't mean it's totally not worth investigating further - as you say the tags are not complicated so probably that hasn't changed.

I had a quick look and the first issue on the issue queue is for the 8 version and it's to do with how libraries are loaded, which I believe did change as 8 moved along. Someone's posted a patch in Dec 16 so not that long ago and it's marked as 'needs review', so best would be to try it out and report back there as to whether that works or not, if so and something else doesn't work then create another issue if you can't fix it yourself, or post another patch if you can.

If you use composer to install Drupal 8, for example using:
https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project

then you can also apply the patch in the patches section of your composer.json by adding the link to the patch so it can find it:
https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/views_rss_itunes-fatal_error_call_to_undefined_function_libraries_load-2839012-3.patch

This is kinda how it works - if you wait it may never arrive, and if you can't do the above it's all googleable skills.